# Most effective way to store user response into boolean variable

Tags: java

This question is regarding general programming and is not language specific, but the code example is with Java. I have a console program in which I want to ask a user a simple question, such as:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

    boolean employed;

    // create a Scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Are you presently employed?  "); // unsure of how to capture user response while keeping the program user friendly
    employed = keyboard.nextBoolean();

    }
```

I want to hold the response as a boolean. However, I am unsure of what the convention or the most effective way to do this would be. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Read a `String` and parse it. For example: `"Y"`, `"y"`, `"Yes"` are `true`, `"N"`, `"n"`, `"No"` are `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is first obtain the response from the user and compare it with known values and then assign boolean values for employed. So it would be:

```
value = keyboard.nextLine();
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")
    employed = true;
else
    employed = false;
```

In this case, if the user enters 'Yes', 'YES', 'yes', 'yEs', etc., it would set the boolean to true.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user to enter `Y` or `N`. Read the next line. Initialize your variable to true if the line is "Y". Initialize it to false if the line is "N". Ask the question again if it's neither "Y" nor "N". You can use a case insensitive comparison to be more forgiving and friendly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[]args){

   boolean employed = false;
   System.out.println("Are you presently employed?");
   String response = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
   if(response.length()>=1 && "Yy".contains(response.charAt(0)){
      employed = true;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide your program with a number of responses that can be reasonably interpreted as TRUE, and some that can be interpreted as FALSE. Reject all other responses as invalid responses.

"Yes" is generally assumed to be TRUE, and "No" is generally assumed to be FALSE. Beyond that, there isn't really a convention.

If the question is not a yes/no question, but some other question with only two valid responses, you have some options. An example question would be "Do you prefer rainy or sunny days?" In those cases, you may want to name some constants to correspond to the two possible answers like so:

```
public static final boolean SUNNY = true;
public static final boolean RAINY = false;
```

Then you can compare the value later against the constants, and your code will still be clear as to what a true or a false value mean for a given variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand it right, but I wouldn't rely on nextBoolean, rather just read the user input string and then compare it to a set of accepted values, for example "y","yes,"true","sure as hell I was" it makes sense to use equalsIgnoreCase(string). This provides a bit more flexibility, also you should at least indicate it your question that what answer you'll accept

Something like

```
System.out.print("Are you presently employed? (y/n) ");
String answer = keyboard.next();
if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
   employed = true;
} else if("n".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
   employed = false;
} else {
//retry, throw exception, handle erroneous user input
}
```